# Serverless Compose throwing symlink error on 'serverless offline'

Tags: node.js, typescript, serverless-framework

I am playing around with serverless-compose and typescript and I am getting the following error when trying to start the project locally.

```
npx sls templateService:offline
Compiling with Typescript...
Typescript compiled.
Environment: darwin, node 14.18.2, framework 3.19.0 (local), plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Error: EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '***/sls-compose-demo/node_modules' -> '***/sls-compose-demo/template-service/.build/node_modules'
Error:
```

It happens when I am running 'npx sls template-service:offline' for the second time (when the `.build` folder has already been generated in the `/template-service` folder). I am using **serverless-plugin-typescript** for building the service.

My folder structure is the following:

```
/template-service
  /.build
  /src
    handler.ts
  serverless.ts
  package.json
serverless-compose.ts
tsconfig.json
package.json
```

serverless-compose.ts

```
const serverlessCompose = {
  services: {
    templateService: {
      path: "./template-service"
    },

  }
}

module.exports = serverlessCompose;
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/types/",
    ],
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020"
    ],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "preserveSymlinks": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./lib/**/*.ts"  
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./dist",
    "./node_modules",
    "./docker",
    "./coverage",
    "./.build",
    "./.serverless",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Update:

It seems like a general problem with serverless compose. It isn't working with either 'serverless-plugin-typescript' or 'serverless-bundle'.
It also produces an error on 'sls deploy' - it is expecting the node modules folder to be inside the sub project folder.

I have opened issues both in the serverless-plugin-typescript and in serverless:
https://github.com/serverless/serverless-plugin-typescript/issues/274
https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/11213

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?